# How to do first n times async loops then one time function in callback way?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is not a question about how to do post multipart form in nodejs.

But how to do such logic(first do a n times loops(async) then one time function(async)) in callback way?

for example, client will post multipart form with normal form fields:

req.files[n]: contains n images, needs to save to server's local filesystem

req.body: contains post.title, post.content, post.user

In normal way(php, java...), sample code would be

```
array savedPath = [];
// save images to local filesystem
foreach image in files
  savedPath.push(saveImageToLocal(image))
// append saved images path to post
var post = req.body;
post.images = savedPath;
Posts.insert(post)
```

But in nodejs, callback way, how can i write it?

```
var savedPath = [];
saveImageToLocal(files[0], function(path) {
  savedPath.push(path);
  saveImageToLocal(files[1], function(path) {
    savedPath.push(path);
    //.... its n elements, how can I write it??
   var post = req.body;
   post.images = savedPath;
   Posts.insert(postfunction(err, result) {
      res.send(err, result)
    });
  });
});
```

Or

```
var savedPath = [];
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  savesaveImageToLocalTo(files[i], function(path) {
    savedPath.push(path);
  });
}
waitSaveToFinished() ??
var post = req.body;
post.images = savedPath;
Posts.insert(postfunction(err, result) {
  res.send(err, result)
});
```

How to do these kind of things in the way of nodejs/callback?

Comment: You want to store values in an array, and each time in your callback check `if (myArr.length == n) { finalize(); }`

Comment: You (or someone just like you) just posted this identical question about 10 minutes ago.  I can't find it now, so perhaps it was closed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Why close it? I think its quite common and really tough for nodejs/callback novice.

Comment: I didn't close anything.  I'm just commenting that I just saw this same question a few minutes ago.  Questions get closed here when they are poorly written.  This is how the site maintains a higher level of quality.  The reasons why they get closed are usually explained either in the reason for closing or in the comments.  New users here sometimes get knocked around a bit in a bit of an unpleasant way until they learn how to write good questions or offer good answers.  I'm not saying that's great, but it happens a lot.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. I have done my best to detail the question in my poor English, why they just close it instead of requesting for more explain on the question? is it because the question is too stupid??

Comment: I'd suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to coordinate multiple asynchronous operation is to use promises.  So, if this were my code, I would change or wrap `saveImageToLocalTo()` and `Posts.insert()` to return promises and then use promise features for coordinating them.  If you're going to be writing much node.js code, I'd suggest you immediately invest in learning how promises work and start using them for all async behavior.

To solve your issue without promises, you'd have to implement a counter and keep track of when all the async operations are done:

```
var savedPath = [];
var doneCnt = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  savesaveImageToLocalTo(files[i], function(path) {
    ++doneCnt;
    savedPath.push(path);
    // if all the requests have finished now, then do the next steps
    if (doneCnt === n) {
        var post = req.body;
        post.images = savedPath;
        Posts.insert(postfunction(err, result) {
            res.send(err, result)
        });
    }
  });
}
```

This code looks like it missing error handling since most async operations have a possibility of errors and can return an error code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've read promise, just exactly what I want.